# Meteor Iron router hooks being run multiple times

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

**EDIT:** [Here](https://github.com/niranjans/testRouter) is the github repo. And you can test the site [here](http://testrouter1.meteor.com/).

On the homepage, just open the browser console and you will notice that `WaitOn` and `data` are being run twice. When there is no `WaitOn`, then the data just runs once.

---

I have setup my pages by extending `RouteController` and further extending these controllers. For example:

```
    ProfileController = RouteController.extend({
        layoutTemplate: 'UserProfileLayout',
        yieldTemplates: {
            'navBarMain': {to: 'navBarMain'},
            'userNav': {to: 'topUserNav'},
            'profileNav': {to: 'sideProfileNav'}
        },
        // Authentication
        onBeforeAction: function() {
            if(_.isNull(Meteor.user())){
              Router.go(Router.path('login'));
            } else {
                this.next();
            } 
          }
     });

ProfileVerificationsController = ProfileController.extend({
    waitOn: function() {
        console.log("from controller waitOn");
        return Meteor.subscribe('userProfileVerification');
    },

    data: function() {
        // If current user has verified email
        console.log("from controller data start");
        var verifiedEmail = Meteor.user().emails && Meteor.user().emails[0].verified ? Meteor.user().emails[0].address : '';
        var verifiedPhoneNumber = Meteor.user().customVerifications.phoneNumber && Meteor.user().customVerifications.phoneNumber.verified ? Meteor.user().customVerifications.phoneNumber.number : '';

        var data = {
            verifiedEmail: verifiedEmail,
            verifiedPhoneNumber: verifiedPhoneNumber
        };
        console.log("from controller data end");
        return data;
    }
});
```

On observing the console in the client, it seems the hooks are being run 2-3 times. And I also get an error on one of the times because the data is not available. The following is the console on just requesting the page once:

```
from controller waitOn
profileController.js?966260fd6629d154e38c4d5ad2f98af425311b71:44 from controller data start
debug.js:41 Exception from Tracker recompute function: Cannot read property 'phoneNumber' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'phoneNumber' of undefined
    at ProfileController.extend.data (http://localhost:3000/lib/router/profileController.js?966260fd6629d154e38c4d5ad2f98af425311b71:46:62)
    at bindData [as _data] (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_controller.js?b02790701804563eafedb2e68c602154983ade06:226:50)
    at DynamicTemplate.data (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_dynamic-template.js?d425554c9847e4a80567f8ca55719cd6ae3f2722:219:50)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_dynamic-template.js?d425554c9847e4a80567f8ca55719cd6ae3f2722:252:25
    at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:2445:26)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:1808:16
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:2043:12)
    at viewAutorun (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:1807:18)
    at Tracker.Computation._compute (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?517c8fe8ed6408951a30941e64a5383a7174bcfa:296:36)
    at Tracker.Computation._recompute (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?517c8fe8ed6408951a30941e64a5383a7174bcfa:310:14)
from controller data start
from controller data end
from controller waitOn
from controller data start
from controller data end
```

Have I not used the controllers properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being able to see the rest of the code that you have defined that uses these route controllers (such as templates or route definitions), I cannot accurately speak to the reason for the data function being called multiple times. I suspect that you may be using the `ProfileVerificationsController` with multiple routes, in which case the `data` definition for this controller would be executed multiple times, one for each route that uses the controller. Since the `data` definition is reactive, as you browse through your application and data changes, this might be resulting in the code defined to be rerun.

As for your controller definitions, I would suggest making a few modifications to make the code more robust and bulletproof. First, the `ProfileController` definition:

```
    ProfileController = RouteController.extend({
        layoutTemplate: 'UserProfileLayout',
        yieldRegions: {
            'navBarMain': {to: 'navBarMain'},
            'userNav': {to: 'topUserNav'},
            'profileNav': {to: 'sideProfileNav'}
        },
        onBeforeAction: function() {
            if(!Meteor.user()) {
                Router.go(Router.path('login'));
                this.redirect('login'); // Could do this as well
                this.render('login'); // And possibly this is necessary
            } else {
                this.next();
            }
        }
    });
```

Notice the first thing that I changed, `yieldTemplates` to `yieldRegions`. This typo would prevent the regions from your templates using this route controller to be properly filled with the desired subtemplates. Second, in the `onBeforeAction` definition, I would suggest checking not only whether or not the `Meteor.user()` object is `null` using Underscore, but also checking for whether or not it is `undefined` as well. The modification that I made will allow you to check both states of the `Meteor.user()` object. Finally, not so much a typo correction as an alternative suggestion for directing the user to the `login` route, you could use the `this.redirect()` and `this.render()` functions instead of the `Router.go()` function. For additional information on all available options that can be defined for a route/route controller, check [this](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#route-options) out.

Now for the `ProfileVerificationsController` definition:

```
    ProfileVerificationsController = ProfileController.extend({
        waitOn: function() {
            return Meteor.subscribe('userProfileVerification');
        },
        data: function() {
            if(this.ready()) {
                var verifiedEmail = Meteor.user().emails && Meteor.user().emails[0].verified ? Meteor.user().emails[0].address : '';
                var verifiedPhoneNumber = Meteor.user().customVerifications.phoneNumber && Meteor.user().customVerifications.phoneNumber.verified ? Meteor.user().customVerifications.phoneNumber.number : '';

                var data = {
                    verifiedEmail: verifiedEmail,
                    verifiedPhoneNumber: verifiedPhoneNumber
                };
                return data;
            }
        }
    });
```

Notice the one thing that I changed, which is to wrap all of your code defined in the `data` option for your controller with a `if(this.ready()){}`. This is critical when using the `waitOn` option because the `waitOn` option adds one or more subscription handles to a wait list for the route and the `this.ready()` check returns true only when all of the handles in the wait list are ready. Making sure to use this check will prevent any cases of data unexpectedly not being loaded yet when you are building up your data context for the route. For additional information on defining subscriptions for your routes/route controllers, check [this](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#subscriptions) out.

As a final suggestion, for your `onBeforeAction` option definition in your `ProfileController`, I would suggest moving this out into its own global hook like so:

```
    Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
        if(!Meteor.user()) {
            Router.go(Router.path('login'));
        } else {
            this.next();
        }
    });
```

Defining this check in the global hook ensures that you don't have to worry about adding your `ProfileController` to all of your routes just to make sure that this check is run for all of them. The check will be run for every route every time that one is accessed. Just a suggestion, though, as you may have reasons for not doing this. I just wanted to suggest it since I make sure to do it for every Meteor app that I develop for additional security.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I will pay attention to the things you mentioned. I am just a little new to Meteor as you can see :). Anyway, I have updated the question with the Github repo and the test site. The hooks are still running twice even after the changes.

Comment: No problem, I totally understand. I have checked out your site and I see how the waitOn and data functions are being executed twice on the homepage. Might you be able to provide your code that uses these controllers, specifically your route definition code? Without being able to see that, it is difficult to determine the exact reason for the logic being executed two times.

Comment: Sure, I have put the repo on Github. Here is the route file - https://github.com/niranjans/testRouter/blob/master/testRouter/lib/router/routes.js

Comment: My apologies, I completely missed that you put that link there earlier. I was thinking this earlier, but now I am sure that it has to do with the fact that you are using `Meteor.user()` in your route controller `data` option. `Meteor.user()` is a reactive data source, which you can read about [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivity). Basically, the routing logic is run once initially when the page loads and runs again once the data from the reactive data source is loaded. This is why you were seeing the `undefined` error, because on first load the data didn't exist on the client yet.

Comment: You can tell that this is the case when you watch how the console messages are printed. The page loads first, initially running the routing logic. The first set of console messages is printed. At this time, the loading template spinner is shown while the route waits for the data from `Meteor.user()` to get to the client. Once the data arrives, the routing logic is rerun again, this time with all the data in place. The second set of console messages is then printed.

Comment: Right. I noticed how `Meteor.user` takes a little time to load. And this causes the computation to rerun. This does make sense. 
So basically, this is not an issue and is a pretty common scenario? In the `data` function, I should just check for when `Meteor.user()` is loaded and then pull in all other info like email or phoneNumber etc?

Comment: Exactly, this is simply normal Meteor behavior and very common indeed. In the `data` option be sure to wrap all of your code in a `if(this.ready()){}` statement if you are waiting on any subscriptions, like you are in this application. With that check in place, you can be sure that the data that you have subscribed to as well as your `Meteor.user()` object has been resolved and loaded up to the client. Please don't forget to mark my answer as correct if I have helped answer your questions. And I hope that you enjoy your future with Meteor and continue to enjoy learning more about it! :-)

Comment: Got it. I really appreciate your help.